# Magento, how to add Terms Agreement in registration?

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento

I have a Magento Ecommerce website. And I am trying to add a text line in the resignation page.

In the **Create an Account Page** I want to add this text under the password field:

**CMS > Page URL key are the same, checked twice**

> By clicking "Submit", I agree to your website's Conditions of Use and Privacy Notice.

And I don't know where to enter this code and how can I make the **Terms of Use and Privacy Notice Underline and in Blue Text**

```
<li>
    <span id="register_notification_row">
    By clicking "Submit", I agree to your website's <a href="{{store url="terms-of-use"}}">Terms of Use</a> and <a href="{{store url="privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode"}}">Privacy Notice</a>.
     </span>
</li>
```

I did some research and find this path to enter the code.

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

Some how the text appear but when I click on the link is not directing me to the page, it just stay in the "Create and Account" page. Plus the URL text are not in blue nor underline.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
<li>
    <span id="register_notification_row">
    <?php
    $terms_url=Mage::getUrl('terms-of-use'); 
    $privacy_policy_url=Mage::getUrl('privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode');
    ?>
    By clicking "Submit", I agree to your website's <a href="<?php echo $terms_url;?>">Terms of Use</a> and <a href="<?php echo $privacy_policy_url;?>">Privacy Notice</a>.
     </span>
</li>
```

`{{store url=""}` is used in wysiwyg editor only.

Comment: Can I also just replace the href= to the url link>?

Comment: means can u tell me ? U can put any url